# DOM update waits for componentDidUpdate to finish?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a component to show a confirmation box.

Confirmation box has two buttons "Yes" and "No", If user clicks "Yes", I call an actioncreator that in turn makes a server call inside componentDidUpdate and if user clicks "No" I do nothing.

I want to ensure confirmation box gets closed immediately in both button clicks.

But I noticed that on clicking button "Yes", my component "ConfirmationBox" waits for componentDidUpdate to finish before closing itself.

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        showActionConfirmationModal: state.showActionConfirmationModal,
        buttonClickValue: state.buttonClickedValue
    };
}

@connect(mapStateToProps,
    {
        closeActionConfirmationModal,
        setButtonClickedValue
    }, undefined, {withRef: true})

export default class ConfirmationBox extends Component {

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        if (prevProps.showActionConfirmationModal && !this.props.showActionConfirmationModal) {
            if (this.props.buttonClickedValue) {
                // Call an actioncreator that makes a server call
            }
        }
    }

    @autobind
    closeConfirmationModal(value) {
        this.props.setButtonClickedValue(value);
        this.props.closeActionConfirmationModal();
    }

    @autobind
    renderConfirmationModal() {
        const {selectedAction, selectedRows} = this.props;

        const confirmationText = "Are you sure you want to take action";
        return (
            <ConfirmationBox
                iconClassName=""
                text={confirmationText}
                buttonOneText="No"
                buttonTwoText="Yes"
                onButtonOneClick={()=>this.closeConfirmationModal(false)}
                onButtonTwoClick={()=>this.closeConfirmationModal(true)}
            />
        );
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {!!this.props.showActionConfirmationModal && this.renderConfirmationModal()}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Any lead here is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you should call the redux action in the parent component (for example in `setButtonClickedValue`), or in child component's `closeConfirmationModal`, there's no reason to use `componentDidUpdate` in your case.

Comment: I was doing it inside closeConfirmationModal, but same was happening there as well. 

Hence I moved this call to componentDidUpdate to ensure component closes first and then an action is called from componentDidUpdate.

Comment: Do you use async redux actions ? (Redux Thunk)